# How to crop UIImage with UIBeziePath with all scale factors?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, crop, uibezierpath

I'm trying to crop a *UIImage* from a given *UIBezierPath* that I've drawn in another view. 
This is my code:

```
// "self.imageEdited" is my initial image that needs to be cropped
let path = .... //my UIBezierPath 
let layer = CAShapeLayer()
layer.path = path.cgPath

self.imageToEditView.layer.mask = layer

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.imageEdited.size, false, 1.0) // <-- Why it's not working with 0.0 ?
self.imageToEditView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

//here "image" will be cropped but it haves white background

let croppedCGImage = image?.cgImage?.cropping(to: path.cgPath.boundingBox)
let croppedImage = UIImage(cgImage: croppedCGImage!)
self.imageToEditView.layer.mask = nil
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(croppedImage, nil, nil, nil)
```

This code works, it crops my image as desired. 
But if I change the scale factor of the ***UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions*** to 0.0 (to get the default scale of the device, this will create the same "*image*" but when it runs this:

```
let croppedCGImage = image?.cgImage?.cropping(to: path.cgPath.boundingBox)
```

I will not get the right image cropped. It crops it as a different portion. 
 should I scale my path?